# Writing an encrypted PDF file using Cipher RSA

Tags: java, pdf, encryption

In the code below, I grab an existing pdf file, encrypt it and then output the encrypted file. My problem is that the outputted file does not work properly. It creates a file of zero bytes. I tried the same code with a simple text file "sample.txt" and it worked fine. The outputted file was created with encryption.

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong? Does it work differently with PDF files?

```
public void encryptFile() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("c:\\sample.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\sample_encrypted");

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSapPublicCertificate().getPublicKey());
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, c);

    byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
    int read;
    while ((read = fis.read(buf)) != -1) {
        cos.write(buf, 0, read);
    }

    fis.close();
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
}
```

EDIT
I should mention that I tried the same thing above but without any cipher/cipherOutPutStream and the new cloned file was generated properly. The code is below. So I would tend to believe its an issue with Cipher or CipherOutputStream. But then again, as mentioned before, it all worked fine with a simple text file.

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int read;
    while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
```

EDIT2 Content of method getCertficate()

```
public Certificate getSapPublicCertificate() throws IOException, CertificateException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    char[] password = "mypass".toCharArray();
    String alias = "myalias";

    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreSapCertificate);
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

    keystore.load(fIn, password);
    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);

    return cert;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what value does the getSapPublicCertificate().getPublicKey()  returns ?

Comment: Hi Jay, I added the method definition above. My pair keys were generated using the info from this 
[link](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/self_signed_certificates_for_a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). You cannot encrypt large files using RSA. I do wonder though how you handle your errors or what you do when your program doesn't finish; issues like these should be caught by the Java runtime system.

The file handling is not different between text files and PDF files, it's just the size that is different.

---

Hybrid encryption comes down to:

1. Generate fully random symmetric key (e.g. AES-128);
2. Encrypt the file, e.g. using AES-CBC with zero IV;
3. Encrypt the symmetric key with RSA-OAEP or RSA-PKCS#1;
4. Send or store the ciphertext and the encrypted symmetric key;

Decryption goes like this:

1. Retrieve the ciphertext and the RSA encrypted symmetric key;
2. Decrypt the symmetric key using the private key;
3. Decrypt the ciphertext.

Comment: Hi,

Let me see if I understand this hybrid system and please correct me if I'm off. I need to encrypt the file using a symmetric algorithm. Then encrypt the symmetric key and the symmetrically encrypted file together using the public key.

Then, I use the asymmetric private key to decrypt it all. This will give me the symmetric key and the encrypted file. I then use the symmetric key to decrypt the symmetrically encrypted file. 

Am I close?

Comment: Close indeed, I'll put it in the answer.